# Copying files from one sub directory to another

Tags: linux, directory, cp

I think I must be missing something obvious. I am in a directory called `AmHist`, with 2 subdirectories, `Assign` and `Resources`. I want to move 2 files from `Assign` to `Resources`.

I try

```
cp LinuxHist Linuxnotes.txt Resources
```

but for both files I get `No such file or directory`. If I do

```
cp Assign/LinuxHist Linuxnotes.txt Resources
```

it only copies `LinuxHist` and I get the error again for `Linuxnotes.txt` on how it doesn't exist. I am very new to linux, so am I missing something basic about relative and absolute paths? I know the basics of Windows command line, so it's not completely alien, but I think I must be missing something big

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the directory name for both source files:

```
cp Assign/LinuxHist Assign/Linuxnotes.txt Resources
```

(There are many more ways of writing this, but this is the simplest form of the command to understand).

Now your title has "Copy" but the question says "move".  The `cp` command will copy.  If, instead you want to move the file then use the `mv` command:

```
mv Assign/LinuxHist Assign/Linuxnotes.txt Resources
```

Comment: Is it possible to move or copy files while I am in the Assign subdirectory to the Resources subdirectory?

Comment: Yes, in a similar way that you would with Windows; `..` means up a level.  So  `cp LinuxHist Linuxnotes.txt ../Resources`

Comment: Ok, thank you! It's hard to wrap my mind around this way of dealing with directories, being so used to windows

Comment: There are differences, but the only ones for what you are doing here are names of commands and `/` instead of `\ `. Note a better syntax is `cp -t ../Resources LinuxHist Linuxnotes.txt` now the first is the special/destination, and there are no odd behaviour issues for when the target does not exist. Read `man mv`/`man cp` and always use option `-t` or `-T` (this applies the same for `mv`, `cp`, `ln`).

Answer (score 0):

You can go to first your source directory i.e assign by using `cd` command. After that, you can use this:

```
mv LinuxHist Linuxnotes.txt ../Resources
```

This will definitely work.